# How should I use the Do while Loop in correct way?

Tags: excel, vba

Q:
I am trying to create VBA code to achieve few things:

Take data from each row of the reference sheet and update the data.
Example
Sheet1:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Sheet 2:
Formula1= "=""Row number"& Reference from sheet1 , output= Row number 1

After updating the data for Row 1 it should save the message as .txt and save sheet name with Reference of the same Row number "1"

The next iteration will be for row 2.
The iteration should keep following the loop as long as i<some defined number.

The above is just an example. Please refer the below code and advise how to use the "i" in concatenation and file name. When I now run this formula, "i" shows in excel formula and gives "#NAME?" instead of the output.

Code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'

    Dim Path As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Path = "C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\"
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Filename = Range("Sheet1!J2")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    Path & Filename & ".txt", FileFormat:= _
    xlTextPrinter, CreateBackup:=False
          
    Do While i < Range("Sheet1!L1")
        
        Filename = Range("Sheet1!J2")
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        Path & Filename & ".txt", FileFormat:= _
        xlTextPrinter, CreateBackup:=False
        
        Range("A1").Select
        
        
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=""01""&"",""&Sheet1!R[1]C[1]&"",""&Sheet1!R[2]C[1]&"",""&Sheet1!R[1]C[9]+i+1&"",""&Sheet1!R[4]C[1]&"",""&Sheet1!R[5]C[1]&"",""&Sheet1!R[6]C[1]&"",""&Sheet1!R[7]C[1]&"",""&Sheet1!R[14]C[1]&""/"""
        Range("A2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=""02""&"",""&Sheet1!R[1]C[1]&"",""&Sheet1!RC[1]&"",""&Sheet1!R[9]C[1]&"",""&Sheet1!RC[9]+i&"",""&Sheet1!R[11]C[1]&"",""&Sheet1!R[12]C[1]&"",""&Sheet1!R[13]C[1]&""/"""
        Range("A3").Select
        Filename = Range("Sheet1!J3") + i
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
            Path & Filename & ".txt", FileFormat:= _
            xlTextPrinter, CreateBackup:=False
            
        
        i = i + 1
    Loop
     
End Sub
```

Comment: This Row says "Compile Error. Function not defined" :  'Formula1() =.....'

Comment: Removed that row, that shouldn't have been there.

Answer (score 0):

In your R1C1 formulas try changing `"",""&Sheet1!RC[9]+i` to `"",""&Sheet1!RC[9+i]` This will increment columns by i. As for the filename:

```
Filename = Range("Sheet1!J3").Value + i
```

Also it would be better practice to either store `Sheet1` as a variable, or call the Ranges like this:

```
Filename = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J3").Value + i
```

Comment: I tried  changing "",""&Sheet1!RC[9]+i to "",""&Sheet1!RC[9+i] but I am getting following error: Run time error : 1004 . Application defined or Object defined error,

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it should have been `" & 9 + i & "` instead of just `9+i` (my editor yells at me if I don't add spaces, so might be worth adding those too